# Two different gre scores

Tags: graduate-admissions, graduate-school, exams, gre

so I gave my gre for the second time and got a score of 160 in quant and 146 in verbal. However first time I got 158 in quant and 150 in verbal. Which score do I send to the university or do I send both the scores.

Answer (score 1):

This is something that you may well ask your prospective universities.  Also depends on which fields you are planning on pursuing.  Second score seems *overall* better, but your question doesn't have a lot of information to go off of.

I would note that if your program doesn't weigh GRE nearly as much compared to GPA and research experience (let alone making it optional for reasons such as COVID) that this wouldn't necessarily be something worth tearing your hair out for.